# IE and Edge renders page much slower than Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web, frontend, microsoft-edge

What can the problem be when a web page loads slow for 20-30 seconds when I am trying to request my server via IE or Edge **over the internet** but fast with Chrome and Firefox?

The attached picture shows that the request is over and done with after 3.85 s then there is about 20 s before the next request fires and after that it loads the entire page.

I was first thinking that it might have to do with rendering, but oddly enough it renders at similar speed as Chrome and Firefox when I try it on IE or Edge **locally**.

Is there some way to find out what the client is doing during these 20 or so seconds?

[image]

*No other resource files are loaded or downloaded in between the two items shown in the picture.*